# How to get components rendered inside JTree (Swing Component Hierachy)

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtree

For some specific purpose I am trying to manipulate UI by just accessing Swing/AWT component hierarchy, and I am stuck at JTree.

I have a JTree which is rendered using a custom TreeCellRenderer, and have JCheckBox in each node.

[image: Sample JTree]

I am trying to obtain a specific JCheckBox object used to render a specific node, to programmatically change it's state, what I have is JTree Component object.

I couldn't find a way to get the JCheckBox component created to render a specific node.

If I keep calling Container.getComponents() recursively, I reach upto :

```
class javax.swing.JTree
class javax.swing.CellRendererPane
class javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer
```

but these doen't seems to giving out components rendered by custom renderers.

Comment: There is no checkbox created for a specific node. That's not how a renderer works. A single checkbox instance is used to paint all the nodes. To change how a node is displayed, you need to change the model, fire an event, so that the tree knows the model has changed, and asks the renderer to re-render the changed node.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As @JB-Nizet pointed out in comment, I solved my problem by updating custom model object using reflection.

```
Object modelObject = nodeToSelect.getUserObject();
Method method = modelObject.getClass().getMethod("setSelected", boolean.class);
method.invoke(modelObject,true);
```